# Document function guarded by a define?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm trying to document a function guarded by a `#define`. The define is off by default.

```
#ifdef ___FOO_BAR___
  void FooBar(void);
#endif
```

The file is being processed by Doxygen. I have added the `\Fn` command according to Doxygen's [Documenting the code](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) and the section [Documentation at other places](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#structuralcommands):

```
#ifdef ___FOO_BAR___
  //! \Fn void FooBar()
  //! \brief ...
  //! \details ...
  DECLSPEC void API FooBar();
#endif
```

However, the function `FooBar` is not being documented. Using `\fn` makes no difference. And moving the documentation outside the macro's block makes no difference.

How do I instruct Doxygen to produce documentation for the function, even though its guarded by a define (and the define if *off*)?

---

The above is part of an `#if \ #else \ #endif`, so I can't use preprocessor tricks. I want both sets of functions documented. In the `\details`, we explain the function is only available when a particular define is enabled.

---

```
$ doxygen -version
1.8.9.1
```

Comment: This S.O. link might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356120/documenting-preprocessor-defines-in-doxygen

Comment: This one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: @KeithSmith - my bad... I'm trying to document the function, not the define.

Comment: @jww It isn't directly relevant to the question you're asking , but  `___FOO_BAR___` is a reserved name. In this case it is unlikely to cause a problem, but it is good to make a habit of not using them.

Comment: @juanchopanza - OK, thanks. I used three underscores to avoid that problem (some past questions got bogged down on the number of underscores a symbol in a library should have).

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the PREDEFINED tag to control the behavior to you liking. You can check [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html) for more information.

I order to see what is expanded from the doxygen included pre processor try

```
doxygen -d Preprocessor
```