# How to Document C function macros using Doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a C code as below

```
#define RTC_SECOND_MAX 60u
/* Maximum count for the minute */
#define RTC_MINUTE_MAX 60u
/* Maximum count for the hour */
#define RTC_HOUR_MAX   24u

#define FUNC(rettype, memclass) rettype


/*****************************************************************************/
/* Global variable definitions (declared in header file with 'extern')       */
/*****************************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************************/
/* Local variable definitions ('static')                                     */
/*****************************************************************************/

/*****************************************************************************/
/* Local function prototypes ('static')                                      */
/*****************************************************************************/

/** 
 ** \brief CheckClockTime
 **
 ** This checks, if the given clock is meaningful
 **
 ** \return E_OK:     The given clock time is valid
 **         E_NOT_OK: The given clock time is invalid.
 ** \param [in] ClockCheck   clock to be checked
 **
 */
**
static FUNC(Std_ReturnType, AUTOMATIC) CheckClockTime
(
  CONST(Rtc_ClockType, AUTOMATIC) ClockCheck
);
```

Here function "CheckClockTime()" has type which is a function macro "FUNC()". This FUNC() is macro which returns a "rettype".

When I use Doxygen to generate Documentation for this code. I get something as shown in image attached. It seems like Doxygen is not parsing a function type which is a function macro. How can I parse this to Doxygen?

[image: FUNC() is parsed as function but not type]

Comment: https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/preprocessing.html

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2356120/1606345) help?